# Flask url_for not working with parameters

Tags: python, flask

I have a function which takes 1 parameter however it seems, my `url_for` isn't working for some reason

**python code**

```
@app.route('/news')
def news(top):
    client = gnewsclient.NewsClient(language='english', 
                                    location='india', 
                                    topic=f'{top}', 
                                    max_results=50) 

    news_list = client.get_news() 
    topics = client.topics
    return render_template('news.html', data=news_list, data2=topics)
```

---

**Html Code where url_for is being used**

**home.html**

```
<a href="{{url_for('news', top='world')}}">News</a>
```

**news.html**

```
    {% for item in data2 %}
        <a id="link" href="{{url_for('news', top= item)}}">
            <div id="topic" style="color: white">{{item}}</div>
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the parameter `top` in the route decorator since `news(top)` view has already a `top` parameter

```
@app.route('/news/<top>')  # -- HERE --
def news(top):
    [..]
    return ..
```